# Relay email from a specific user through SMTP in Postfix

Tags: postfix

This is a very simple question and sorry if it is obvious/already answered.

I have a mail server that I use to send mail from my primary domain. I have it set up just how I want it with TLS only, DKIM, DMARC, SPF, and an RT record for my domain. It works great.

However, the same host also has a webserver with several php applications with their own virtual domains. I don't want the web server user (http) to be able to send email from my primary domain by submission, there is too much of a chance of getting spam blacklisted, and also it is just weird to get email from the wrong domain.

I want to set up postfix to send all email from that virtual domain (virtual-domain.com) through Google's SMTP servers, and not from my primary domain. I have multiple virtual domains, I would ideally like to pick which smtp server to use for each virtual domain.

Right now, I can only figure out how to do this using the transport file, which as far as I can tell only applies to destination addresses. I can easily make any email to bob@gmail.com go through gmail's smtp servers, but I don't know how to do the same using the from address.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can start to use posfix transport_maps "man 5 transport"

Comment: Thanks for the comment @c4f4t0r, however from reading the manual on transport maps, it seems that those filters are based on destination, not on source. To be more specific: I want to filter email **from** virtual_domain.com to an external smtp server. I do not want to filter email **to** virtual_domain.com. I think I need something with relay_domains, but I am not sure.